# Sencha Touch v2 toolbar title alingment

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

When I create a toolbar like below the title is misplaced to the right of the last button, any ideas how to fix it?

```
        {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'Chat',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Places',
            ui: 'back',
            id: 'backToPlaces'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'spacer'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'People',
            ui: 'forward',
            id: 'toProfiles'
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also fighting with the toolbar. Then I discovered the `navigationbar`.
The title is in the center. With a button aligned left and right. (see align property)

```
 {
    docked: 'top',
    xtype: 'navigationbar',
    title: 'Chat',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'back',
            action: 'back',
            text:'BACK',
            itemId: 'backButton'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'decline',
            action: 'cancel',
            text:'Cancel',
            itemId: 'cancelButton',
            align : 'right'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This component existed in an early preview version of Sencha Touch 2, but no longer exists. Instead, you should use the `Ext.TitleBar` component in Sencha Touch 2.0. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375676/sencha-touch-v2-toolbar-title-alingment/9779522#9779522).

Comment: True. This question and answer was for a beta release. There is also a 'navigationview' in the new release. That simplifies navigation with a back button for you.

Answer (score 4):

just after answered this, i found the "centered" attribute and looked at creation of title element of sencha, so just forget this above and use in your config:

```
var myToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                docked : 'top',
                title: {
                  title: 'my Title',
                  centered: true 
                },
                items : []
            });
```

Comment: I have found this far more reliable than the navigationbar.

Answer (score 0):

In Sencha 2 there is no "special" title element, it is created as simple element in the "items". So i future, you can just add it at right place direcly by placing the config to your docked bar:

```
var myToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                docked : 'top',
                items : [{
                    xtype: 'spacer',
                },{
                    xtype: 'title',
                    title : 'Hello World'
                },{
                    xtype: 'spacer',
                }]
            });
```

Only with spacer it is in the middle.

Comment: For me (v1) this yields: `Uncaught Attempting to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered: title`

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly stated in the docs that NavigationBar is a private class for internal use by the framework http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.Bar and the centered attribute metioned by anj does not work as expected (at least in the latest release).

According to this post http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161082-PR3-Toolbar-title-position-broken-when-spacers-control-button-positioning&p=691928 it is simply a bug that the title is not centered and we should wait for next release. In the meantime you might use navigationbar if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage something similar to how titles in Toolbar behaves of Ext.navigation.Bar. see the Ext.TitleBar  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.TitleBar

This class handles things like long titles for you by automatically adding ellipses and the title is always centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a `NavigationBar` component which is public. It is simply used internally by `NavigationView`. You should **never** use this.

Instead, you should use [Ext.TitleBar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.TitleBar). This allows you to center the `title` config and also use the `align` property on items (normally buttons) to align them to the left or right.

It also has built in support when the title is too long, or any items are too wide. It will automatically limit the length of all items to a certain width, and add ellipse to the title if needed.

Here is a simple example:

```
var titleBar = Ext.create('Ext.TitleBar', {
    docked: 'top',
    title: 'Navigation',
    items: [
        {
            iconCls: 'add',
            iconMask: true,
            align: 'left'
        },
        {
            iconCls: 'home',
            iconMask: true,
            align: 'right'
        }
    ]
});

Ext.Viewport.add(titleBar);
```